# Initialize a javascript widget on each Template Render in Flow Router

Tags: meteor, kendo-ui, meteor-blaze, flow-router

I am having trouble getting my javascript to initialize at the right time during the rendering of the template in Flow Router. This was not a problem for me in Iron Router but I'm new to Flow so I'm a bit baffled what to do.

In my `.onRendered()` I have:

```
$('.ui.dropdown.controls').dropdown();
```

Which will render fine when I first navigate to the page using my routing links. But if I reload the page while sitting on that route, it doesn't initialize properly. I can call the code from the console, and it will work fine and create the proper widgets, but there's some kind of ready state that I'm missing.

Any ideas? hoping this is an easy one. Btw, I'm encountering the same for some other kendo widgets on the same template. So I'm pretty sure it's not the javascript execution but merely a timing thing.

EDIT: This is my route >

```
loggedIn.route('/ticket/:id', {
action: function(params, queryParams) {
    BlazeLayout.render('appSingleLayout', {nav: "topNav", main: "ticketView"});
},
subscriptions: function(params){
    this.register('currentTicket', Meteor.subscribe('ticket', params.id));
    this.register('tagList', Meteor.subscribe('list', 'ticketTags'));
    this.register('agentList', Meteor.subscribe('list', 'ticketAgents'));
},
triggersEnter: [function(context, redirect){
    console.log("Viewing ticket",context);
}],
name: "ticket"
```

});